# How to remove ETX character from the end of a string? (Regex or PHP)

Tags: php, regex, ascii, special-characters, control-characters

How can I remove the ETX character (0x03) from the end of a string? I'd either like a function, otherwise I can write a regular expression, all I want to know is how to match the ETX character in a regular expression? `trim()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To complete Charles' answer, I had a case where the ETX character was not at the end of the line so I had to use the following code:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\x03/', '', $string);
```

Just remove the $ sign.

Comment: Dangerous if you use a multi-byte charset like utf-8 or utf8mb4

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried rtrim function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Answer (score 1):

The [ETX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-text_character) is a control character, which means we have to go through some extra effort to bring it into existence.

From the PHP interactive prompt:

```
php > $borked = "Hello, have an ETX:" . chr(3);
php > print_r($borked);
Hello, have an ETX:
php > var_export($borked);
'Hello, have an ETX:'
php > echo urlencode($borked);
Hello%2C+have+an+ETX%3A%03
php > var_dump( preg_match('/' . chr(3) . '/', $borked) );
int(1)
php > var_dump( preg_match('/' . chr(3) . '$/', $borked) );
int(1)
php > echo urlencode( preg_replace('/' . chr(3) . '$/', '', $borked) );
Hello%2C+have+an+ETX%3A
```

In other words, you can basically just inject the character into the regex string.  Now, this *might* backfire.  This technique may backfire based on character sets and other horrible things.

In addition to `chr(3)`, you could also try `urldecode('%03')` to produce the character.  You can also use a special escape syntax, as listed on the [PCRE syntax pages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php): `/\x03$/`

Here's a function for you, using that last method:

```
function strip_etx_at_end_of_string($string) {
    return preg_replace('/\x03$/', '', $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a guess rtrim($var,"\c"); or preg_replace("/\c+\$/",'',$var);